# Have issue which seems to only effect me on my computer but when I use an online compiler it works

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have this line of code for example and I keep getting an error sayin

```
NameError: name 'stop' is not defined
```

When I use an online compiler it works and I get a similar error in other projects I have and I have no idea what to do.

```
sum = 0
largestnum = 0
count = 0
sumofeven = 0

while True:
    numbers = input("Enter a sequence of integers. Enter 'stop' to exit. \n")
    if numbers == "stop":
        break
    else:
        count +=1
        sum += int(numbers)

        if str(numbers) > str(largestnum):
            largestnum = numbers
        if int(numbers) % 2 == 0:
            sumofeven += int(numbers)
print("Sum: " + str(sum))
print("Average: " + str(sum/count))
print("Largest number: " + str(largestnum))
print("Even Sum: " + str(sumofeven))
```

Comment: What happens if you add a line at the start of your code: `stop = "Test value"` ?

Comment: There is not name `stop` here...

Comment: Copy-paste this whole code to your script editor. Possibly you wrote `stop` and not `"stop"`.

Comment: Please paste the full error message, just in case.

Comment: I rolled-back the post to the version with the code, because without it, with just the error message, the answer looks disconnected is missing a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably do *not* use Python-3.x. You probably use Python 2.7.

In 2.7, function `input()` attempts to evaluate your input as if it were a Python expression. It treats `stop` as a name of a variable that you, indeed, have never defined.

Solutions: Either switch to Python-3.x or call function `raw_input()`. The latter function returns the input without interpreting it.

Comment: Hi, I checked my version and its 3.8 any other suggestions.

Comment: You would not have _this_ error in _this_ code with 3.8. 2.7 is the only possibility. Check again.